# Grouped list in a specific type

Tags: c#, linq, list

My Structure :

```
public struct MyStruct
{
    public int MyStructId;
    public decimal Properties1;
    public string Properties2;
    ...
}

var myList = new List<MyStruct>();
```

My data inside for example :

```
MyStructId   Properties1  Properties2
==========   ===========  ===========
1            2.5m         test 
1            1.0m         test2
2            2.2m         test3
1            1.8m         test4
2            2.9m         test5
```

My target is to browse grouped list of my specific type. Something like that :

```
foreach (List<MyStruct> myStruct in myList.GroupBy(m => m.MyStructId))

foreach (List<MyStruct> myStruct in myList.GroupBy(m => m.MyStructId).Select(g => new { myStruct = g.ToList()}).ToList()))
```

The Linq expression should be return a `<List<List<MyStruct>>`.
What is the best way to do it ?
Thanks to help me.

Comment: Not related to your question but do you have a compelling reason to use a `struct`? [Choosing Between Class and Struct](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229017(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should give you the expected result:-

```
List<List<MyStruct>> myStruct = myList.GroupBy(m => m.MyStructId)
                                      .Select(g => g.ToList()).ToList();
```

If you want to use this directly in a `foreach` loop then you can ignore the last `ToList` :-

```
foreach (List<MyStruct> myStruct in myList.GroupBy(m => m.MyStructId)
                                          .Select(g => g.ToList()))
{

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to convert result to `<List<List<MyStruct>>`. In fact, you can iterate through results directly:

```
foreach (var group in myList.GroupBy(m => m.MyStructId))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Group = {0}", group.Key);
    foreach (var item in group)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Item = {0}, {1}, {2}", item.MyStructId, item.Properties1, item.Properties2)
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help, I would like a list because I want add some new elements to this list.